# Is there a way to have a select and creatable hybrid?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have been using the `select` from react-select for some time. So far, only with predefined options, without any functionality for adding any other option/s.

As far as I could read up and figure out, there is also something called `creatable`, which is exactly doing that. But it doesn’t allow my to predefined/static lists, as far as I could see.

I assume both have to be implemented to get either functionality, or is there a way or prop to just stick one of them?

Edit:
Maybe I didn’t emphasis to enough on the static part. Basically, I would like to have one component that has a prop like: “canAddOptions: bool”. To either allows to add values or not. As far as I can understand, I have to implement both to get this..?

Comment: which version you are using

Comment: 3.0.x would I need to back to 2.x.x?

Comment: Can you share list, because creatable also allows you to define static list as options

Comment: Whilst preventing to add any new values? Will do, currently on my phone 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also using similar approach in my application, where I'm rendering static list as options and it should work as a `creatable` select.

As per the problem statement, you can use `isValidNewOption={() => false}` to make `creatable` as normal select.

Try something like below:

```js
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';
 
 <CreatableSelect
    isMulti
    isValidNewOption={() => false} // You can apply condition here as per the prop you will get.
    options={[
      { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
      { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
      { value: 'three', label: 'Three' },
    ]}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, but I won't be able prevent that new options are getting created created. A prop like `preventNewOptions: bool`.  ...this is what I what I meant by "hybrid" between the `Select` and the `CreatableSelect`. I usually wrap 3rd parties into my own components, to prevent to much of a dependancy hell. I was just hopping I can set a prop on my existing `Select` impl. But I guess, I need to implement both to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: try ` isValidNewOption = {() => false}` instead of `preventNewOptions`

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-eibjy

Comment: I'm updating my answer. If it solves your problem. You can accept it.